# Return multiple results with index terraform

Tags: oracle, terraform

I currently have the below lists,

```
local.security_list =
    [
    {
       ocid = security_list_id_1
       name = subnet1
    },
    {
       ocid = security_list_id_2
       name = subnet1
    },
    {
       ocid = security_list_id_3
       name = subnet2
    },
    {
       name = subnet2
       ocid = security_list_id_4
    },
    ]

var.vcn_security_lists = [
{
  security_list_name = security_list_1
  subnet_name = subnet1
},
{
  security_list_name = security_list_2
  subnet_name = subnet1
},
{
  security_list_name = security_list_3
  subnet_name = subnet2
}
]
```

I want to create the security lists using the var.vcn_security_lists list and then assign them to the subnet later on by using the subnet_name field. I have done this previously using the index() function as below, which loops through a subnet and pulls out the security list with the same subnet name. The problem is that this only returns one item - how can I return multiple from a list ?

```
subnet_security_list_ocid           = [local.security_list[index(local.security_list.*.name,var.vcn_security_lists[index(var.vcn_security_lists.*.subnet_name,var.vcn_subnets[count.index].subnet_name)].security_list_name)].id]
```

Comment: "using the index() function" - what have you done? Do you have any TF code example?

Comment: I have added my index function to the post

Comment: What is `var.vcn_subnets`? Can you please provide complete code that causes your issues? What is the context of `subnet_security_list_ocid`? Where and how do you use it? Also what's wrong with the code? Any errors?